# The origin of "В тридевятом царстве, в тридесятом государстве"

Tags: этимология, выражения

"**В тридевятом царстве, в тридесятом государстве**" ("in a Faraway Land") is a phrase that is used in numerous Russian fairytales.

Why is царство - тридевятое (3-9ое), and государство - тридесятое (3-10ое)? What is the origin of the phrase?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a number of ethnographic and cultural studies about what the тридевятое царство, тридесятое государство was in fact, but I believe, that is not the matter of your question.

Linguistically, **тридесятый** is an Old-Russian numeral denoting **тридцатый**, the thirtieth. And **тридевятый** seems to be a wordplay based on тридесятый and the fact that it is far enough for one to stop counting. (Compare: сто пятьсот раз.) **The thirtieth kingdom and furthieth country, if you count from our border** - that's how it can approximately be understood by the listener. Nobody knows the name of that country, for nobody's been there.

**furtieth** is a wordplay denoting a non-existing numeral. You can think of your own one if you please.